# Extract content from text file using java

Tags: java

I have a text file that is layed out like this:

```
57363 Joy Ryder D D C P H H C D
72992 Laura Norder H H H D D H H H
71258 Eileen Over C F C D C C C P
70541 Ben Dover F F F P C C C F
46485 Justin Time F C F C D P D H
61391 Anna Conda D D F D D F D D
88985 Bob Down P F P F P F P P
```

and I have the following code that reads this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Filename: ");
        // C:\\Users\\Vick\\PT\\accountFilesDemo_17259747\\src\\accountFilesDemo_17259747\\Grades.txt
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        File myfile = new File(filename);

        try {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myfile);
            while(inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                String str = inputFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            inputFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I want to know how I can get the student ID which is the first 5 digits and store them somewhere, and then after the student name the 8 letters which are ie  D D C P H H C D how do I put these somewhere to hold a value from 1-8 and then I need to add them up and do some math to get a total, and then how do I write these two the student ID and total to seperate text file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a Scanner to separate the tokens of a single line.

```
String str = "57363 Joy Ryder D D C P H H C D";

    Scanner tokens = new Scanner(str);

    String studentID = tokens.next();

    String name = tokens.next();

    String surname = tokens.next();

    String letters = "";

    while(tokens.hasNext())
    {
        letters = letters + tokens.next() + " ";
    }

    System.out.println("ID = " + studentID +
                       "\nNAME = " + name +
                       "\nSURNAME = " + surname + 
                       "\nLETTERS = "+ letters);
```

Comment: That's exactly I'm looking for and had problems with, now I'll figure out how to use the rest myself. I searched all over place for an example because I read and learn from examples, pure theory and text is hard to deconstruct but thank you

Comment: *"...pure theory and text is hard to deconstruct"* - I would strongly advise you to **try to do something about that**.  If you can only learn from examples then: 1) You will be limited in what you can learn by the existence of examples.  As you do more complicated / advanced the work, you will run out of examples ... and people willing to write them for you.  2) In my experience, learning from examples tends to be shallow.  You learn what to do, but not why.  And the "why" is often very important.

Comment: This is why I *try to* avoid spoon-feeding solutions (examples) to people who are learning to program.  You learn more, and more deeply if you have to work at it.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Use `Scanner` to break up each line into the components.
2. Create a class to hold the information in each row.
3. Use arrays if you know beforehand how many elements there will be in the array, and use lists (e.g. `ArrayList`) if you don't.
4. Once you have populated the data structure, then doing the arithmetic and printing the results is simple programming.

These hints answer most of your questions.  But I'm not going to code up your homework for you.

Comment: 1. How do I use the scanner to break lines into components of what I need?

Comment: and what do you mean by create a class to hold information? and as for array lists would using vector be easier?

Comment: 1) Read the javadoc for the `Scanner` class.  2) You know what a class is?  You know how to declare fields, constructors, methods?  3)  The `Vector` and `ArrayList` APIs are almost identical, but `ArrayLists` is preferable for other reasons (that are not relevant here ...).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String str = "57363 Joy Ryder D D C P H H C D";
String[] items = str.split(" ");
```